# Long url address invades wrapped figure area

Tags: url, wrapfig

I wrote the following in a tex file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%-> Defining the paper size, margin widths, and borders:
\usepackage[a4paper,
                top=11mm,           bottom=11mm,
                left=11mm,          right=11mm,
                headheight=0mm,     headsep=0mm,
                footskip=5mm,
                marginparsep=0mm
                %,showframe
                ]{geometry}
    \setlength{\parindent}{3em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%-> To hyphenate long url addresses:
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

%-> Packages for image floats:
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, float}

%-> Package for font (and other elements) color:
\usepackage{xcolor}




\begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
        {\color{gray}
        \rule{0.35\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}}
    \end{wrapfigure}
De acordo com o site da Agência Espacial Europeia, a Estação Espacial Internacional (ISS em inglês) tem sua órbita em torno da Terra cujo período de revolução é de apenas 90 minutos \url{http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Where_is_the_International_Space_Station}. Sabendo disso, calcule o valor do semieixo maior de sua órbita. Dica: de acordo com o site da NASA, a Lua orbita a Terra segundo uma trajetória elíptica cujo perigeu e apogeu ocorrem a 0,363 Gm e 0,406 Gm, respectivamente, e seu período de revolução é de 27,32 dias \url{https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEhelp/moonorbit.html}.

\end{document}
```

The gray bar is meant to be a wrapped figure. See that the long url invades the picture area, even when I am using the `url` package to hyphenate it. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: There are no suitable breakpoints. You could try `\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}` instead of url, it allows much more.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer, but stiil not working. :/

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I am using Overaleaf V2, and the error message is: "LaTeX Error: File `xurl.sty` not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems using `xurl`, which loads `url` , like this:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
```

solves the problem:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Bernard. But it is still not working. :/

Comment: Does the very code you posted, modified as indicated, work?

Comment: No, @Bernard, it doesn't. If needed the info: I am using Overleaf V2, and the error message is "LaTeX Error: File xurl.sty not found."

Comment: Maybe it isn't installed yet, as it is a recent package. I don't  know the way Overleaf works exactly, but maybe you can put `xurl.sty` in the same folder as your main file. It can be downloaded from [here, on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl).

Comment: The great advantage I found as using (formerly Sharelatex) Overleaf is that I don't need to keep installing packages every time. This is the first time I was forced to save an "sty" file to run my work. But ok, I think I can live with that and hope it will not become frequent. Thank you all, guys!